# Compute sum for distinct order numbers in ssrs report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm using a SQL Server 2008R2 Database and SSRS Report Builder 3.0
Trying to compute the sum of the amount owed for each order id (need to show the itemids)...but when I do, the amount owed is showing 400 (instead of 200 - line 4, 100 instead of 50 in line 7, line 9 is correct. As a result the Total line is way off)

```
=Sum(Fields!owe.Value)
```

The report is grouped by the campus.
I understand that ssrs is probably not the best place to do this computation but I don't know how to do outside of ssrs....I tried distinct and group by so far with no results.
Below is how I need the report to show like....
Thanks in advance.

[image: This is how I need the report to show]

Incorrect amounts are
[image]

Another example as it should display the subtotals
[image]

Comment: It is calculating it correctly.  200+200=400.  And 50+50=100.  Not sure where the 40 is coming from for line 9 though... can you show a screen shot of what it *actually* looks like for comparison?

Comment: Hi dub stylee...the second picture is the incorrect one...The amount owed for orderid 100 is $200...etc...

Comment: The reason is because since you have it broken down by `itemid`, each row has the full amount of that order (200 for order a).  How are you getting the values for `F2` and `F3`?

Comment: The results in f2 and f3 are being produced in a temp table...far away from my eyes. I just need to compute the subtotals...and if I remove the itemid I'm fine, but if I add itemid I get thrown off.

Comment: That is a problem with grouping data.  Especially if you do not have control over the data you are getting.  It is doing exactly what it should, based on your explanation.  It sounds like F2/F3 are the total amount for that order, so rather than taking the sum of them, just take the maximum (they should always be the same, so maximum will just give you 200 for order a).

Comment: Your expression for Subtotal is to SUM, and that's what it is doing.   Unless there's some bit of logic you haven't told us about, I think you could use AVG(), MAX() or MIN() and get the results you say you want.

Comment: Well if I use MAX(), then if I have another order for campus 'a' for example where they owe another 100, it is only going to take the max of those...so it is not going to work

Comment: I see now what you need to do.   Problem is I have no idea how to do it in just the SSRS.   I would handle it in the SQL.

Comment: How would you handle it in SQL @TabAlleman? I'm fine with working in SQL instead and then edit my SSRS report. Pretty please.

Comment: First way that comes to mind is add an additional column to the resultset, called "OrderOwe".   It would be the value of owe for the first item in each order, and would be zero for all other items in the same order.   Then in SSRS, in the sub-total box, I would sum "OrderOwe.Value" instead of "Owe.Value".   OrderOwe would not have to appear in the tablix.

Comment: @TabAlleman, I like that solution...can you help me to get started on it...not sure how to exactly code this in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify the SQL to produce an extra column just for purposes of summing the Owe on an OrderId.   Use the Row Number to get the first item in each order, and only supply the Owe value for that item for each order:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId ORDER BY ItemId) AS rn
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE (whatever filters you use)
)
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN Owe ELSE 0 END AS OrderOwe
FROM cte
ORDER BY Campus, CustomerId, OrderId, ItemId
```

Then simply change the expression for the "Owe" textbox in your SubTotal row to this:

```
=Sum(Fields!OrderOwe.Value)
```

And you will get the sum of the Owe per order instead of per item.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your owe is always the same for each item in the group you could add a Sum/Count of the item in the group which would give you the correct results in all the cases above.

Comment: So if for order 1, if itemid 400 is 200 and 401 is 210 what would they owe?

Comment: It's not well-illustrated, but I think the "owe" is tied to the order, not to the item.   It would be clearer if the example showed a campus with more than one order.

Comment: Yeah it seems Owe is really not related at all to this data, without a query i don't see a solution possible. Owe appears to be completely arbitrary.

Comment: I guess I am saying if Owe is different for each line item in an invoice, and the sum of it is now the total owed for that invoice. It makes no sense. If it is difference and the sum is the total it makes perfect sense or if the total per row is the same as the total for all.